# how to identify if checkbox is selected or not in javascript using "this" for id selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function validate()
   {
       if ($(this).prop("checked") === false)
       {
           alert("was unselected");
           counter++;
           $(this).prop("checked", true);
       }
       if ($(this).prop("checked") === true)
       {
           alert("was selected");
           counter--;
           $(this).prop("checked", false);
       }
}
```

I have four checkboxes on selection or deselect i want to increment or decrement the counter variable,I tried above code but not working.

Comment: use `else if` for the second if, otherwise the second if will be true always

Comment: It also depends on the context where `validate()` is invoked, as the `this` may not be referring to the object you have in mind. How are you using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can user Jquery (is) for checking and make sure you can access the counter variable outside the function. Otherwise, define it as closure.

```js
$('input').on('change', validate)
let counter = 0
function validate(e){
   if($(e.currentTarget).is(':checked')){
      counter++
      alert('checked')
   } else {
     counter--
     alert('uncheck')
   }
   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Test 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="test">

<label>Test 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="test">

<label>Test 3</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="test">

<label>Test 4</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="test">
```